# If x = 2 y = 5 z = 0 then find values of the following expressions: a. x == 2 b. x != 5 c. x != 5 && y >= 5 d. z != 0 || x == 2 e. !(y < 10)

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

If

```
x = 2 
y = 5 
z = 0
```

then find values of the following expressions:

```
x == 2 
x != 5 
x != 5 && y >= 5 
z != 0 || x == 2  
!(y < 10)
```

So this what I did code in Java. I want to code this in Python now. This has to work with boolean. But I'm stuck at the implementation in Python.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Python uses `and`, `or`, and `not` instead of `&&`, `||`, and `!`. With those substitutions, those expressions become valid python.

Comment: This question might be liable to **downvotes** since it might not be useful.

Comment: @Geshode the intended code is on the bottom section. Fixing the code is strightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several differences between Java and Python.

One of which is the use of 'if' statements.

In python, an 'if' statement follows this structure:

**if CONDITION:**

**elif CONDITION:**

**else:**

The operators are also slightly different.

Rather than **||** it's **or**

Rather than **&** it's **and**

Boolean works similarly, except python capitalizes the first letter. **True False**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

```
x = 2
y = 5
z = 0

print(x == 2)
print(x != 5)
print(x != 5 and y >= 5)
print(z != 0 or x == 2)
print(not (y < 10))
```

which yields

```
True
True
True
True
False
```